# Error with try to connect oracle db with ruby

Tags: ruby, database, oracle

I'm trying to connect by ruby to a oracle db, but I've an error:
OCIError: ORA-12514: TNS:el listener no conoce actualmente el servicio solicitado en el descriptor de conexión
oci8.c:659:in oci8lib_240.so 
The listener don't know actually the requested service in the connection descriptor.

- I downloaded the instant client  12_2 and the odbc to w7 64b and the oci.dll to w7 32b and I put it in the ruby folder. 
  (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winx64soft-089540.html)
- I downloaded the db 11g release 2 to w7 64b, and I run the setup. I configurer the listener since NET MANAGER. 
  (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/index.html)
- I have the sql developer and the connection and the querys works ok.
- I configured the tnsnames.ora, listener.ora and sqlnet.ora

tnanames:

```
SERVICE_PODVCT_ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = podvct.x.com)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = PODVCT)
      (SERVICE_NAME = PODVCT)
      (SID = PODVCT)
    )
  )
```

listener:

```
LISTENER_PODVCT_ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = podvct.x.com)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA = 
    (SERVICE_NAME = PODVCT)
    (SID = PODVCT)
    )
  )
  sid_list_LISTENER_PODVCT_ORCL=
   (sid_list=
   (sid_desc=
   (oracle-home=C:\app\user\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1)
   (sid_name=PODVCT)))
ADR_BASE_LISTENER_PODVCT_ORCL = C:\app\user
```

sqlnet:

```
AMES.TRACE_DIRECTORY = C:\app\user\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\NETWORK\trace
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NTS)
NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES, HOSTNAME)
NAMES.TRACE_FILE = names.trc
NAMESCTL.TRACE_FILE = namesctl.trc
NAMES.PREFERRED_SERVERS =
  (address_list =
    (address = (protocol = tcp)(host = podvct.x.com)(port = 1521))
  )
NAMES.LOG_FILE = names.log
NAMESCTL.TRACE_LEVEL = ADMIN
NAMES.LOG_DIRECTORY = C:\app\user\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\NETWORK\log
NAMES.DEFAULT_DOMAIN = world
NAMESCTL.TRACE_DIRECTORY = C:\app\user\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\NETWORK\trace
NAMES.TRACE_LEVEL = ADMIN
ADR_BASE = C:\app\user
```

I configured the environment variables:

```
PATH: ...;C:\Ruby24-x64\bin\oci.dll;C:\Oracle_odbc;%ORACLE_HOME%/network/bin;C:\app\PRIVE2\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin;
ORACLE_HOME:C:\app\user\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1
ORACLE_SID:podvct
NLS_LANG: SPANISH_SPAIN.WE8MSWIN1252
TNS_ADMIN: C:\app\USER\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\NETWORK\ADMIN
```

- And in ruby I put:

  require 'dbi'
  require 'oci8'

  //dbh = OCI8.new(user,password,'podvct.x.com:1521/PODVCT')

  dbh = DBI.connect("DBI:OCI8:podvct.x.com:1521/PODVCT",user,password)
- I checked the connection since ruby and since sqlplus and the error is:

  dbh = DBI.connect("DBI:OCI8:podvct.monsanto.com:1521/PODVCT",user,password)

**OCIError: ORA-12514: TNS:el listener no conoce actualmente el servicio solicitado en el descriptor de conexión
oci8.c:659:in oci8lib_240.so
The listener don't know actually the requested service in the connection descriptor.**

Comment: whether db and listener is running ?

Comment: the db is a remote db and it is running in a server, and the listener in my pc.

Comment: did you confirm, if listener on server is also up ?

Comment: Need I a listener in the both ? the server and my pc? I need configured the listener like in my pc? I'll confirm it.

Comment: yes.. server should have listener and should be up

Answer (score 0):

I try with all and the response is put the ruby sentence like this:

dbh = DBI.connect("DBI:OCI8:SERVICE_PODVCT_ORCL",user,pass)

SERVICE_PODVCT_ORCL is the name of the service in the tnsnames.ora

thanks!